# Dynamically resizing width and wrapping nested flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div nested a couple layers deep in some flexboxes that dynamically changes width depending on how long the text within it is.

Is it possible to get the containing flexboxes to also change widths and wrap as needed purely with CSS? If not, I'm open to any JavaScript solutions.

Here's a visual for a better idea of what I'm talking about:

[image: Nested flexboxes]

If anyone wants to play around with it, here's a code snippet:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.root {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.level-2 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.level-3 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container root">
  <div class="flex-container flex-item level-2">
    <div class="flex-item level-3">
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item level-3">
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container flex-item level-2">
    <div class="flex-item level-3">
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some longest text over here</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item level-3">
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would say no, dealing with nested and non-sibling elements is almost impossible with pure CSS especially for your third case, maybe 1 and 2 are possible

Comment: Aw, bummer. I wasted so much time trying to figure this out! Haha. If that's the case, I'm open to any JavaScript solutions.

Comment: well this is only *my* opinion ;) maybe some CSS wizards will bring some magic :)

Comment: I also don't see a way to do this with pure CSS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif how would you go about doing number 2?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Curious to see how you could get the blue containers to grow (and maintain min-width of 50%) without the text wrapping first.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can see for this it to have the first and second case. It's not 100% perfect but on the resize you will see the transformation between the 1 and the 2:

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.box {
  flex:1 0 50%;
  background:blue;
  border:1px solid;
  display:flex;
  padding:10px;
}
.box > span {
   background:#fff;
   border:1px solid;
  flex:1 0 50%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span>some text<br>some text long long long long text<br>some text</span>
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
    <span>some text<br>some text<br>some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should look at this :

```js
function check(){
  var str = $('#text').val()  

    if (str.length < 15) {
      document.body.innerHTML = '';
      document.write('<style>');
      document.write('    .big_container{');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color: grey;');
      document.write('      padding: 6px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 47%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .redrectangle{');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 49%;');
      document.write('      background-color: red;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .big_container2{');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      flex-wrap: wrap;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color: grey;');
      document.write('      padding: 6px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container2{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('      margin-bottom: 10px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container3{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 105px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      flex-wrap: wrap;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('      margin-bottom: 10px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .redrectangle3{');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      margin-top: 1px;');
      document.write('      background-color: red;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('</style>');
      document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">');
      document.write('<\/script>');
      document.write('<input id="text">');//
      document.write('<button onclick="check()">Go !');
      document.write('</button>');


      document.write('<div class="big_container">');
      document.write('<div class="container">');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle"></div>');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle">'+str+'</div>');
      document.write('</div>');
      document.write('<div class="container">');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle"></div>');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle"></div>');
      document.write('</div>');
      document.write('</div>');

    }else if (str.length  < 35) {
      document.body.innerHTML = '';
      document.write('<style>');
      document.write('    .big_container{');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color: grey;');
      document.write('      padding: 6px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 47%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .redrectangle{');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 49%;');
      document.write('      background-color: red;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .big_container2{');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      flex-wrap: wrap;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color: grey;');
      document.write('      padding: 6px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container2{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('      margin-bottom: 10px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container3{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 105px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      flex-wrap: wrap;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('      margin-bottom: 10px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .redrectangle3{');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      margin-top: 1px;');
      document.write('      background-color: red;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('</style>');
      document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">');
      document.write('<\/script>');
      document.write('<input id="text">');//
      document.write('<button onclick="check()">Go !');
      document.write('</button>');


      
      document.write('<div class="big_container2">');
      document.write('<div class="container2">');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle"></div>');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle">'+str+'</div>');
      document.write('</div>');
      document.write('<div class="container2">');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle"></div>');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle"></div>');
      document.write('</div>');
      document.write('</div>');
    }else{  
      document.body.innerHTML = '';
      document.write('<style>');
      document.write('    .big_container{');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color: grey;');
      document.write('      padding: 6px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 47%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .redrectangle{');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 49%;');
      document.write('      background-color: red;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .big_container2{');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      flex-wrap: wrap;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color: grey;');
      document.write('      padding: 6px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container2{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      justify-content: space-between;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('      margin-bottom: 10px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .container3{');
      document.write('      padding: 5px;');
      document.write('      height: 105px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      display: flex;');
      document.write('      flex-wrap: wrap;');
      document.write('      background-color:blue;');
      document.write('      margin-bottom: 10px;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('    .redrectangle3{');
      document.write('      height: 50px;');
      document.write('      width: 100%;');
      document.write('      margin-top: 1px;');
      document.write('      background-color: red;');
      document.write('    }');
      document.write('');
      document.write('</style>');
      document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">');
      document.write('<\/script>');
      document.write('<input id="text">');//
      document.write('<button onclick="check()">Go !');
      document.write('</button>');


      
      document.write('<div class="big_container2">');
      document.write('<div class="container3">');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle3">'+str+'</div>');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle3"></div>');
      document.write('</div>');
      document.write('<div class="container3">');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle3"></div>');
      document.write('<div class="redrectangle3"></div>');
      document.write('</div>');
      document.write('</div>');
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input id="text"><button onclick="check()">Go !</button>
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. it's not about creating the 3 layouts but it's the same layout that change depending on content

Comment: Oh my god what's this? ... sorry but you still didn't get the question, this is a static layout dynamically created and not a dynamic layout

Comment: Well, you can't say I didn't try :p